# Load parent and child table in one query linq to entitiy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a following tables/classes structure in Linq to entities.

```
Books
{
 bookId,
 Title
}

Tags
{
  TagId
  Tag
}

BooksTags
{
 BookId
 TagId
}
```

Now I need to write a query which gives me result like this

```
Class Result
{
 bookId,
 Title,
 Tags
}
```

Tags should be comma separated text from the tags table by joining all three tables.
How to get it done.

Thanks

Parminder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(from b in books
select new { BookId = b.BookId,
             Title = b.Title,
             Tags = bookTag.Where(bt => bt.BookId == b.BookId).Select(bt => tags.Single(t => t.TagId == bt.TagId).TagTitle)
           }).ToList().Select( t => new 
           { BookId = b.BookId,
             Title = b.Title,
             Tags = string.Join(", ", t.Tags.ToArray())
           }
```

Comment: thanks stephan
but i get the error
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Join(System.String, System.String[])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

regards
Parminder

Comment: In that case you'll want to pull back the Tags as a List<Tag> and then join them on the client side.  I'll edit to show.

Comment: That was just awesome. Fantastic.

Thanks a lot Stephan
Parminder

Comment: as the tables are joined in the model, so i cut it down bit

(from b in context.Books
                         select new
                         {
                             BookId = b.BookId,
                             Title = b.Title,
                             Tags = b.BooksTags.Select(bt => bt.Tags.Tag)
                         }).ToList().Select(t => new
                         {
                             BookId = t.BookId,
                             Title = t.Title,
                             Tags = string.Join(", ", t.Tags.ToArray())
                         });

thanks